# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors' when using System.Text.Json in Godot C# android build

Tags: c#, android, godot

Whenever I try to deserialize a class using the System.Text.Json nuget package, I'm getting the exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

I've manually installed the System.Numerics.Vectors nuget package into the project but the error still persists.

**Edit:**
I haven't found a solution yet and I ended up switching over to Json.NET (Newtonsoft's Json package), which works fine with Godot on all platforms.

Comment: If this is the error I tackle quite a bit at work, this can happen when 2 conditions are met:
1. There is more than one version of the said assembly in transient and/or directly referenced.
2. One of the packages (I think it was the lower version) has a assembly version that does not match the version provided to nuget. I forgot the name of the two different fields. The assembly version must have 3 decimals and can't contain characters unlike the others.
The assembly

Comment: As a result we need more details about your project dependencies to assist.

Comment: I'm using the packages GodotOnReady and System.Text.Json, but I suspect this may be a Godot-related issue. This only happens to my android builds and my desktop builds work fine.

Comment: If this issue only started occurring after you added System.Text.Json then it's not a godot related issue, there is a dependency conflict that can be solved used multiple methods.  There's a few ways to tackle this issue: (1) Select a version of `System.Text.Json` that has a transient dependency on `System.Numerics.Vectors` that matches the same assembly version as `4.1.4.0` or (2) a bunch of work adding binding redirects and referencing the later (or greater if API matches) version in nuget for `System.Numerics.Vectors`.. This may results in other packages having the same error so repeat.

Comment: I apologize but I'm in the dark about handling dependencies in C#. Could you elaborate on how what a transient dependency is and how I could go about selecting a version of System.Text.Json for that?

Comment: Also there are many existing posts online and questions regarding this error. Some contain general answers, others don't.

Comment: There's are many ways. The way I've been using so far is to download different versions of the "complained-about assembly" from nuget using download package button. Change extension to zip. Extract it, then navigate to the package that would best fit godot (usually the latest version of .net standard is fine as long as it's compatible with godot). You can then use `gac` in `Developer powershell for VS ` which would come with visual studio. You load the assembly into cache version by version and then check the assembly version to see if it matches `4.1.4.0`.

Comment: Once you are done finding the nuget version that you need then you should ensure to unload the assembly from the `gac` otherwise you may encounter problems in the future.

Comment: You can then find the corresponding version of `System.Text.Json` that has this same assembly version as a dependency [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json), but make sure you are looking under the correct version of .net. In this case you are lucky to have it listed here sometimes it's transient and not listed.

Comment: A simpler solution for someone who knows what they are doing is to force reference the later (or even later than that) version of `System.Numerics.Vector` in their project using nuget and then add a [binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/how-to-enable-and-disable-automatic-binding-redirection) which could look different depending on project type. I don't know much about godot infrastructure to add details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Godot is running on mono and mono is not having a good time with System.Text.Json right now. I suggest using Newtonsoft.Json for now until this gets resolved.